# How to run a docker with aws serverless

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, virtualbox, serverless, aws-serverless

I am trying to deploy a serverless function but I am running into some problems with docker. I am working on Windows 10 and have installed docker. I have created a vm using the command:

```
docker-machine env virtualbox
```

When I run serverless deploy, it gives me the error:

```
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.39/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon conf                                                                 iguration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

I then tried running the command:

```
  eval "$(docker-machine env virtualbox)"
```

And I got a little progress but ended up with an error saying:

```
$ serverless deploy
Serverless: Generated requirements from 
C:\Users\Desktop\folder\requirements.txt 
in C:\Users\Desktop\folder                                                                
QL\.serverless\requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from 

C:\Users\Desktop\folder\.serverless\requirements\requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Docker Image: lambci/lambda:build-python3.6

Error --------------------------------------------------

docker: Error response from daemon: create 
"/c/Users/folder/.serverless/requirements": 
"\"/c/Users/Desktop/folder/.serverless/requirements\"" includes invalid characters 
for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you 
intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.                                                            
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated!

Comment: Can you share your requirements file?